# String to timestamp Android

Tags: java, android, timestamp

I have the following string:

> 19 July 2016 at 07:00:00 UTC

and am using the below code to convert it to a timestamp. However the console is throwing the following error:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "19 July 2016 at 07:00:00 UTC" (at offset 2)

CODE:

```
String time = todayAt7;

DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
try {

    Date date = sdf.parse(time);
    System.out.println("Date and Time: " + date);

} catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Essentially I am trying to figure out the timestamp for 'today at 7am', is there a way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: What is your todayAt7?19 July 2016 at 07:00:00 UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");` is not correct. The string argument should match the format of the date string your are trying to parse

try below

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd mmmm yyyy 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want timestamp at today 7 AM, you can try the below

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Output:

```
Tue Jul 19 07:00:00 EDT 2016
```